SENT transmission decoding CRC
I am decoding a SENT transmission (Enhanced serial message format with 12-bit data field and 8-bit message id) for an electronic sensor and have it set up to find each packet of 18 messages and read the required data for the CRC (given in the first 6 messages as the sync bit #2). My output of my code is as follows (Python):
Packet in message:
 1 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 2 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 3 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 4 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 5 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 6 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 7 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
 8 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
 9 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '1100']  
10 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
11 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
12 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
13 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
14 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0110', '0000', '1101', '0100', '1011']  
15 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0110', '0000', '1101', '0100', '1011']  
16 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
17 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
18 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '1100']  

CRC:    011000
Data 1: 101010
Data 2: 100011
Data 3: 100001
Data 4: 110100

Packet in message:
 1 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']   
 2 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 3 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 4 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0110', '0011', '1100', '0100', '0000']   
 5 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 6 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 7 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 8 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']   
 9 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '1100']   
10 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
11 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
12 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
13 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0000', '1101', '0100', '0111']  
14 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
15 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
16 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
17 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
18 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '1100']  

CRC:    111111
Data 1: 100010
Data 2: 000110
Data 3: 001101
Data 4: 000000

Packet in message:
 1 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 2 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0011', '1100', '0100', '1100']   
 3 ['1100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 4 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 5 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 6 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']   
 7 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 8 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']   
 9 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0011', '1100', '0100', '1100']   
10 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
11 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0000', '1101', '0100', '0111']  
12 ['1000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0011', '1100', '0100', '1100']  
13 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0000', '1101', '0100', '0111']  
14 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
15 ['0000', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1011', '1100', '0100', '1110']  
16 ['0100', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '0101']  
17 ['0111', '0011', '1110', '0101', '0000', '1101', '0100', '0111']  
18 ['0111', '0011', '1110', '0101', '1000', '1101', '0100', '1100']  

CRC:    001000
Data 1: 000010
Data 2: 100001
Data 3: 000000
Data 4: 101010

The first block contains the full packet of data with the CRC checksum, and Message Data bits at the bottom. The following two images contain the same information but for different packets.
With an online calculation, the verification output with the checksum CRC appended onto the end of the data messages (32 total bits) with the polynomial x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + 1 will return 0b000001 for almost all messages. I was wondering if the output for the verification could be changed so that instead of 0b000000, the output for a successful transmission was 0b000001?
The link to the website I used for calculation is here: https://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/index.php?Polynom=1011001&Message=000000%0D%0A000000%0D%0A001011%0D%0A110100%0D%0A011001
